# Flex/AIR Encryption/Decryption library (alternative to as3crypto)

Tags: apache-flex, encryption, air, as3crypto

Hey stackoverflow community,

I was wondering if anyone knew of any built-in Flex libraries that support encryption/decryption. I see that most people recommend AS3Crypto, are there other alternatives?

In particular, looking for one that supports DES encryption.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

as3corelib offers some encryption functionality, you may find it a little more approachable than as3crypto library. Can browse as3corelib here

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/